# Got from a column in a csv to a list, now struggling to get to z-scores

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working with some Electrodermal data in Python and hoping to be able to calculate and graph z scores for my data. My data is structured as a single column in a csv. I've managed to get as far as importing this and turning it into a list with this:

```
 import csv
 with open("1538130011EDA.csv",'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
        print row       
import numpy as np
EDAdata = np.genfromtxt('1538130011EDA.csv',delimiter=',')
EDAlist = EDAdata.tolist()
print EDAlist
```

Then I imported the zscore function from scipy and checked it was working:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
print zscore([1, 2, 3])
```

I'm not sure how to apply that to EDAlist, whether I can outright do that or need to transform that list in some way first.

I'm really sorry if this is a dumb question or i've overlooked something really simple. I am very much a beginner and really just need this one bit of code to help me get started on my project. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You should be able to just do `zscore(EDAlist)` to get z-scores from that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `zscore` to any `array` like object, your `list` is an array like object so you can apply the function directly on your list like:

```
zscore(EDAlist)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!